# All permission and users are correct still getting failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, apache, upload, permissions, centos

UPDATED: It was .com instead of .org in my php, so much pain over something so small

This is driving me absolutely nuts, I've been all over this site, google and every where in between searching for solutions and I've tried everything.  Currently here:

CentOS 6, apache 2

iptables turned off
User group: ftpdir
users in group: root, apache, fwf (my ftp user, ftp works fine)
directory permissions, all enabled for testing purposes

```
rxwrxwrxw on /srv/www/floridawinefest.com/public_html/
rxwrxwrxw on /etc/tmp/
```

php.ini has safemode disabled, file upload enabled, temp directory set to /etc/tmp, max file size 5mb been testing with a 200k file

ran chown on public_html directory with apache:ftpdir

ran chown on etc/tmp directory with apache:ftpdir

ran chmod recursively on all files and directories within /public_html

Still getting below error when trying to upload a file

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/srv/www/floridawinefest.com/public_html/topBG.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /srv/www/floridawinefest.org/public_html/uploader.php on line 11 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/etc/tmp/php9TTyoR' to '/srv/www/floridawinefest.com/public_html/topBG.jpg' in /srv/www/floridawinefest.org/public_html/uploader.php on line 11
```

My code:

```
chmod($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 0777); 

$success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/srv/www/floridawinefest.com/public_html/" . $filename_full);
echo "Succes: " . $success . "<br />";
chmod($filename_full, 0777);

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}
```

Comment: Looks like very strange problem, anyway - what user apache is run under?

Comment: I see mixing of .org and .com in your error message.  Wrong path maybe?

Comment: Weird! Might not make much sense but have you considered/tried generating timestamp based tmp_name? And also, is the file visible under /etc/tmp directory?

Comment: oh... my... god.... I just spent so many hours on this and it was the  .com/.org.  Thank you so so so so much.  File uploads still not working in my wordpress installation, but working in my test script so on to the next part!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So true story (since it's been answered). We had a kid who wrote some upload code like this. Dumped it into a directory. Never checked anything (just like your code doesn't). Years go by and some idiot in Turkey uploaded a PHP script. Nearly took over the server (we had something that blocked his rootkit at the kernel level, security in layers for the win). So something to consider

1. NEVER upload into your root. Create a directory and, if you can, turn off PHP processing for that directory (can be done via .htaccess). Removes all the risk from file uploads.
2. CHECK YOUR FILES. In your case you want an image. A great way to validate this is to use something like the GD libraries and functions like `imagecreatefromjpeg` to make sure it is what it says it is.

Comment: For sure, its deleted, I'd never build an upload without any checks for production use